# Как правильно составить запрос к MySQL с сортировкой

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Ситуация: есть таблица (`id - int; title - varchar; hd - tinyint; source - tinyint; active - tinyint;`) в `mySQL`, с которой нужно одним запросом достать данные с такой сортировкой:

```
1. hd >= 3 AND source <> 5
2. hd >= 3 AND source = 5
3. hd = 2
4. остальное, т.е. hd < 2
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать правильно и одним запросом?

Благодарю.

С уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from table
order by case when hd >= 3 AND source <> 5 then 1
              when hd >= 3 AND source = 5 then 2
              when hd = 2 then 3
              else 4
         end

Подобным образом решился вопрос.